# Reabrir actividad cerrada con onbackpressed()

Tags: java, android

tengo 3 actividades: La principal, una secundaria y una tercera poco importante.

Cuando se abre mi aplicación por primera vez, se ejecuta la actividad principal que tiene categoría launcher, y de acuerdo a un shared preferences que contiene un booleano true llamado primeraVez, despues se ejecuta un if(primeraVez) que dentro llama a la actividad poco importante y pone el primeravez del sharedprefences en false para que nunca mas se ejecute ese if.

La actividad poco importante es un layout que simplemente te pide tu nombre y 
también contiene un botón que después de haber escrito tu nombre te manda a la actividad secundaria.

Ahora bien todo funcionaría bien, pero si a alguien se le ocurriera darle al botón de atrás cuando se encuentra en la actividad poco importante se cargaría la actividad principal. Y claro la persona no me ha escrito el nombre ni nada, para evitar esto sobrescribí el método onBackPressed() de la actividad poco importante y puse moveTaskToBack(true) de modo que se sale de la aplicación y la deja en segundo plano.

Mi intención es que al volver a abrir la aplicación se ejecuta la actividad poco importante para que me pida el nombre.

Eso no pasará porque se ejecutara la aplicación principal y como el if ahora es false pues no volverá a ejecutarse la actividad poco importante.

¿Alguna idea para conseguir mi proposito de una forma idónea y simple?

**EDIT**

He resuelto el problema con tu segunda solución editando el sharedPreferences en la clase poco importante, el código ha quedado así:

Declaro una variable booleana llamada firstTime fuera de todos los métodos en la clase principal

Código onCreate() clase principal:

> ```
>     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
> ```

```
    firstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", true);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Estoy en onCrete()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Código onResume() clase principal:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

    firstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", true);

    if(firstTime) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Lista.this, Bienvenida.class);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Estoy en onResume()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Código del método que se ejecuta al presionar botón acceder en la clase poco importante que me llevará a la clase secundaria:

```
public void acceder() {

    if(comprobar().length() > 0) {

        Intent i = getIntent();

        i.putExtra("nombre", comprobar());
        i.putExtra("inscrito", "si");

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("first",false);

        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Bienvenida.this, MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);


    }   else {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.comprobar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);

        toast.show();

    }



}
```

Código método onBackPressed() de la clase poco importante:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    moveTaskToBack(true);

}
```

Comment: la variable `primeraVez` la puede declarar como `static` y después la llamas desde el método `onBackPressed()` y le cambias el valor a `true`. Para llamarla seria algo como `MainActivity.primeraVez = true`.

Comment: Hola, me gusta tu solucion muy simple y funcional, yo ya la habia pensado, me preguntaba si es una practica buena pasar informacion a traves de variables estaticas, se recomienda hacerlo a traves de los propios intents pero en este caso me pareceria apropiado hacerlo asi. ¿Es entonces la solucion correcta?

Comment: ya lo probaste y si lo probaste, te funciono?

Comment: Otra opción es acceder al mismo `SharedPreference` donde almacenas el valor booleano de `primeraVez` desde el método `onBackPressed()` y modifica el valor a false.

Comment: Pues la primera manera, la de la variable que te respondí no ha funcionado lo cual me ha dejado muy desconcertado, como es posible que no funcione. Voy a probar usando el sharedPreferences como has mencionado en tu ultimo comentario

Comment: Con el sharedPreferences tampoco funciona, recuerda que tengo un movetasktoBack en el backonPressed() de la actividad poco importante para que se salga, al home si le doy a atras  y luego al entrar se ejecute la actividad principal y en teoria el sharedPreferences al cambiarlo tambien en el backonPressed() a true pues deberia otra vez mandarme a la actividad poco importante cosa que no pasa, Sera por el movetasktoback() ?

Comment: En mi comentario te dije que debías modificar el valor a `false`, error, me refería a `true`. Declaraste el SharedPrederence antes del método `moveTaskToBack(true)`? Otra cosa es, seria bueno que editaras tu pregunta y agregaras el codigo de las 3 clases. Ver el codigo es mejor que ver una explicacion, de esa manera las respuestas pueden ser mas precisas. Literalmente ahora he estado dando palos a ciega.

Comment: No te preocupes que me di cuenta y lo puse a true, no funciono, luego me di cuenta de que la comprobacion del if estaba en oncreate luego no se ejecutaria ya que el oncreate() no se volveria a ejecutar, por lo que puse el codigo en onResume(): no funciono tampoco, muy raro, algo se me escapa ahi, por supuesto el sharedPreference lo declare y edite el valor booleano con el editor antes de llamar al metodo movetasktoback() para que tuviera efecto, con todos estos datos mencionados no funciono. Mañana edito la pregunta y le añado imagenes, ahora mismo son las 3:12 hora España y ya no me da tiempo

Comment: Hola he solucionado el problema (he editado mi pregunta con el código que he utilizado para ello),he usado tu solución de editar el sharedPreferences, ayer no funcionaba porque había olvidado usar commit(), como ves el codigo que hay en onResume() es el que tiene el condicional que si se ejecuta me lleva a la clase poco importante asi como dos lineas del sharedPreferences, puesto que esta clase es la principal y el método onResum() será el que se ejecute mas veces de toda la aplicación me preguntaba si es una buena práctica tener todo ese código en onResume()

Comment: Aunque lo que hay dentro del if no se va a ejecutar una vez dado el botón aceptar en la clase poco importante porque se pondrá el valor del sharedPreferences a falso me preguntaba si es una buena manera de hacer las cosas. Si me puedes contestar como lo ves y ya doy por finalizado el tema y tu respuesta como correcta

Comment: Entonses lo pondre como respuesta

Comment: Los login funcionan de la misma manera. Por lo que diría que si, es una forma correcta de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el método `onBackPressed` debes de acceder al mismo SharedPreference donde almacenas el valor booleano y modifícarlo a `true`.

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("first", true);
    editor.commit();

    moveTaskToBack(true);

}
```

Comment: Recuerda que aparte de aceptada también puedes darle un voto a favor. Tal como se explica en el [recorrido de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).